# Qt cached table example changes all rows to first value on submit

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to implement the QT cached table example in my code. However, when i try to change the value of a single attribute in a particular record and click submit, the entire set of records is updated with that same value (duplicates). 
I have a total of 32 records which get updated upon clicking submit.

I am a beginner with Qt and do not understand how this can be fixed. Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

PS: QT creator version 4.4.1 / Based on Qt 5.9.2 (MSVC 2015, 32 bit)

Comment: Share code you implemented as its not an issue with example itself